# How to display a 100% width stripe in a CSS design using a fixed-grid blueprint?

Tags: html, css, blueprint-css

Not sure that the title is really describing what I am trying to do. Actually, this is quite simple and widespread usage over the internet :

I want in the background some liquid/full width of stripes (with the same height of some div of the design) while my content is using a Blueprint fixed-grid.

For instance, this website : [intient.com](http://intient.com/) is doing exactly what I am looking for. A background stripe in black (and another one in grey) that is liquid width and the content using a grid (but not Blueprint after having a look at the CSS)

I am using a Blueprint fixed-width grid (950px) for displaying any content.
Do you know how I can do that? With Blueprint? And without a static background image...

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Blueprint, you do this:

```
<div class="stripeContainer">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="span-8">Column 1</div>
     <div class="span-8">Column 2</div>
     <div class="span-8 last">Column 3</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="span-12">Body goes here</div>
  <div class="span-12 last">Some sort of menu perhaps</div>
</div>
```

Then you style `.stripeContainer`:

```
.stripeContainer
{
    width: 100%; /* this is usually implied */
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I have tried your solution but it is not working. The pink  "stripeContainer" is displayed before the body and not in background.
My code is:
<div class="stripeContainer">..</div>
<DIV class="container"><DIV id="header">..</div></div>
with style:
body #header { height: 120px; background-color: #000000; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; float: left; margin-right: 0; width: 950px;}

Comment: Ok. It works. I needed to add to the stripeContainer style the following :  "position: absolute; z-index: -1;    width: 100%"
Thx